# Testing DSS service from C# application

Tags: c#, service, robotics

I have implemented a service for a robot we have. The service itself is running, however i would like to test it from another application, instead of using VPL to test, because i would like to be able to set breakpoints in my service and have manual control over the requests i send to the service.

I am unable to find any example, sample or solution that shows how to do this. I think i should be using the DSSEnvironment class but there is little to no help to be found online on how to do this.